# Why can't import JXLS.h in obejct that inherits from NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jxls

I use cocoaPods in my project and I pod **JXLS** library in pod. But it's very strange that Xcode show me error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpkaQ.jpg) when I import it in my custom class that inherits from `NSObject`. Nothing happened when I import "`JXLS.h`" or `<JXLS/JXLS.h>` in a subclass of `UIViewController`. I don't know why to will be like this.

Comment: It's very strange that I do the same thing in another new project, but it works well. Even I configured two project in the same way. I couldn't figure out and finally I change my NSObject-Inherited class to UIViewController so that the compiler build my project succeed.